# OpenCV does not save videos

Tags: python, opencv

The below code is supposed to capture a video and save it.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.filters import gaussian

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('My video.avi', fourcc, 10, (640,480))

while capture.isOpened:
    ret, frame = capture.read()

    if ret==True:
        frame = gaussian(frame, sigma=5, multichannel=True)

        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('My video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

capture.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, I get the following error:

`` error: OpenCV(3.4.3) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.3\modules\videoio\src\cap_ffmpeg.cpp:296: error: (-215:Assertion failed) image.depth() == CV_8U in function 'cv::`anonymous-namespace'::CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG_proxy::write' ``

If I remove the gaussian blur, the code works. What is wrong?

Comment: The `gaussian()` returns floats, whereas the videowriter wants unsigned chars.

Comment: @Mark `frame = np.uint8(frame)` does not help me either, I get a black screen

Comment: Try multiplying by 255 before `uint8`... and what do you mean *"it doesn't help"*? The error has gone away - that's a step forward, isn't it? 

Comment: I couldn't agree more :-) OK, I got your point: had to do `frame = np.uint8(255 * frame)`. This did the trick!

Comment: I just found the solution to a problem here thanks to you guys. Maybe considere posting and accepting as answer. Even it's an old thread it might be worth :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.filters import gaussian
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X', 'V', 'I', 'D')
videoWriter = cv2.VideoWriter(
    r'output_video_path', fourcc, 10.0, (640, 480))

while (True):

    ret, frame = capture.read()

    if ret:
        frame = gaussian(frame, sigma=5, multichannel=True)
        cv2.imshow('video', frame)
        frame = np.uint8(255 * frame)
        videoWriter.write(frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

capture.release()
videoWriter.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```